# Bad clustering results with mahout on Reuters 21578 dataset

Tags: mahout

I 've used a part of reuters 21578 dataset and mahout k-means for clustering.To be more specific I extracted only the texts that has a unique value for category 'topics'.So I ve been left with 9494 texts that belong to one among 66 categories. I ve used seqdirectory to create sequence files from texts and then seq2sparse to crate the vectors. Then I run k-means with cosine distance measure (I ve tried tanimoto and euclidean too, with no better luck), cd=0.1 and k=66 (same as the number of categories). So I tried to evaluate the results with [silhouette measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silhouette_%28clustering%29) using custom Java code and the matlab implementation of silhouette (just to be sure that there is no error in my code) and I get that the average silhouette of the clustering is **0.0405**. Knowing that the best clustering could give an average silhouette value close to 1, I see that the clustering result I get is no good at all.
So is this due to Mahout or the quality of catgorization on reuters dataset is low?

PS: I m using Mahout 0.7

PS2: Sorry for my bad English..

Answer (score 0):

I've never actually worked with Mahout, so I cannot say what it does by default, but you might consider checking what sort of distance metric it uses by default. For example, if the metric is Euclidean distance on unnormalized document word counts, you can expect very poor quality cluster quality, as document length will dominate any meaningful comparison between documents. On the other hand, something like cosine distance on normalized, or tf-idf weighted word counts can do much better.

One other thing to look at is the distribution of topics in the Reuters 21578. It is very skewed towards a few topics such as "acq" or "earn", while others are used only handfuls of times. This can it difficult to achieve good external clustering metrics.